# AS3 won't remove EventListener #1009

Tags: actionscript-3

> Error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a
>   null object reference.    at ball3gamehelp_fla::MainTimeline/hitTest()

I'm currently trying to make it so when you catch 2 balls it takes you back to the home page but, when I catch 2 balls it loads the home page and keeps the array of the balls adding to stage, tried multiple ways to remove the event-listener

Also tried to removeball if it reaches a certain pixel but that inst working  either

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to remove the ball from  array when it was removed from stage.

   ```
   function hitTest(evt:Event) :void
   {
       var length:int = bgame.length - 1;

       for ( var j:int = length; j >= 0 ; j--) 
       {
            if (bgame[j].hitTestPoint(Bmitt.x, Bmitt.y, true)) 
            {
                 trace("true");
                 removeChild(bgame[j]);
                 bgame.splice(j, 1);//remove from array
                 Score++;
                 Scoreinstance.text = String(Score);
            }

        }
   ```

   }
2. clear interval in exit function

   ```
   clearInterval(interval);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***removeEventListener***.
For example
`removeEventListener(SomeEvent, SomeHandlerName)`